# running an excel macro via cmd

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

I wrote a VBA code that takes an excel file and unmerge all the cells in it and copy the value from the merged cell to the newly unmerged cells.
when I'm running the code in the excel it is working well.
when I'm trying to run the cod via the cmd I'm getting an error.
I the code executed from the cmd because it need to run on multiple excel files via SAS.

the VBS code is:

```
Sub UnMergeFill(ByVal ws As Worksheet)

Dim cell As Range, joinedCells As Range

For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
    If cell.MergeCells Then
        Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
        cell.MergeCells = False
        joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
    End If
Next

End Sub

sub UnMergeFillAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    for Each ws In Worksheets
         UnMergeFill ws
    Next
End Sub
```

The cmd command to run the code:

```
"C:\Users\sm\Documents\work\excel_macro\UnMergeFill.vbs" "C:\User\sm\Documents\work\excel_macro\r.xlsx"
```

the error messege I'm getting is:

script:
c:..\UnMergefill.vbs

line: 1

char: 26

error: expectef ')'

code 800A03EE

source Microsoft VBScript compilation error

Thank you all for helping

Comment: Would you like to run VBA code as VBS code? [Here](https://help.mjtnet.com/article/19-converting-office-vba-to-vbscript) is a short introduction how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but looking at the error code as well as your VBA code, I think that the issue (or at least one of the issues) is that you are missing some parentheses.

```
sub UnMergeFillAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    for Each ws In Worksheets
         UnMergeFill(ws) 'Added parentheses
    Next
End Sub
```

Try running your code with those and see if it helps. Thanks and Good Luck!